# SwiftUI TabView index view not respecting page view index

Tags: swiftui

My goal is to keep the source of truth for the current TabView index within app state. But I'm not seeing the behaviour I expect from the SwiftUI TabView index indicator.

What I can do is have one of either two outcomes: Have the binding update the source of truth properly, OR have the indicator work as expected. I can't seem to have both.

I've stripped down my code to a test case below. I expect the TabView index view (the indicator) to update and display the current view's index position in the array of the TabView's content (relatively of course, so + 1).

What happens is that the index doesn't update at all. In the original code it actually *lags* by one..

Can anyone with more experience with this setup offer any suggestions or point out where I'm going wrong?

```
import SwiftUI

class Item: Identifiable {
    let id = Int.random(in: 0..<1000)
}

class SourceOfTruth: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item] = [Item(), Item(), Item()]
    /// Source of truth for app state
    var _selectedItem: Int? {
        willSet {
            print("\(newValue ?? 0)")
        }
    }
    /// Exposed SwiftUI binding
    public lazy var selectedItem: Binding<Int> = Binding<Int>(get: {
        self._selectedItem ?? -1
    }, set: {
        self._selectedItem = $0
    })

    init () {
        _selectedItem = items.first?.id
    }
}

struct BindingTestView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: SourceOfTruth

    var body: some View {
        if appState.items.count > 0 {
            TabView(selection: appState.selectedItem) {
                ForEach(appState.items) { item in
                    Text("\(item.id)")
                            .tag(item.id)
                }
            }
                    .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
                    .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
        } else {
            Text("No items")
        }
    }
}

@main
struct SwiftUICombineTestingApp: App {
    let appState = SourceOfTruth()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            BindingTestView().environmentObject(appState)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `@Published` so the variable can be observed by the view:

```
@Published var _selectedItem: Int? {
    willSet {
        print("\(newValue ?? 0)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Did my original idea not work because I wasn't using the `@Binding` property wrapper in the view itself? If so would that be the more conventional way?

Comment: Per my last comment, instead of injecting `@EnvironmentObject appState` and using the class object, have the `@Binding var` in the view and inject by appState at view init?

Comment: Just tried removing the `@Published` wrapper from `_selectedItem` and injecting the Binding into a `@Binding var` in the view, and the indicator now does the 'lagging by one' thing.

Comment: @elight I don't really know what was your original idea with `@Binding`. But the `@Published` solution should be fine here. If you still have more questions please create a new post and I'll try to help you there.